# Python IntFlags behavior for 0 item

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, enum-flags

In the below example codes which uses `IntFlag` of `enum` in Python3, I can understand the first 5 behaviors.
But I cannot understand the last 3 behaviors. I think these results should be `False`. Can anyone elaborate on these behaviors? And any idea how can I define the CLEAR which makes the 3 results ‘False’?

```
In [3]: from enum import IntFlag, auto

In [4]: class Functions(IntFlag):
   ...:     CLEAR=0
   ...:     FUNC1=auto()
   ...:     FUNC2=auto()
   ...:     FUNC3=auto()
   ...:     FUNC12=FUNC1|FUNC2
   ...:     ALL=FUNC1|FUNC2|FUNC3
   ...:

In [5]: Functions.FUNC1 in Functions.FUNC12 #OK
Out[5]: True

In [6]: Functions.FUNC2 in Functions.FUNC12 #OK
Out[6]: True

In [7]: Functions.FUNC3 in Functions.FUNC12 #OK
Out[7]: False

In [8]: Functions.FUNC12 in Functions.ALL #OK
Out[8]: True

In [9]: Functions.ALL in Functions.FUNC12 #OK
Out[9]: False

In [10]: Functions.CLEAR in Functions.ALL #?
Out[10]: True

In [11]: Functions.CLEAR in Functions.FUNC12 #??
Out[11]: True

In [12]: Functions.CLEAR in Functions.FUNC1 #???
Out[12]: True
```

Comment: Int flags work using bitfields. All the bits present in 0 (i.e. no bits at all) are present in any int.

Comment: i.e.  if `flag` is zero, then `(flag & number)==flag` is true for any `number`.

Comment: @khelwood and if using a string analogy, the empty string is present in all non-empty strings

Comment: "how can I define the CLEAR which makes the 3 results ‘False’?"— Don't set it to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLEAR` represents the empty set of flags.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntFlag) never seems to explicitly mention this, but as far as I understand it, the `in` operator tests whether the flags on the left-hand side are a subset of the right-hand side.

However, the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/enum.py#L871) for the `Flag.__contains__` method (which is inherited by `IntFlag`) supports this understanding – this method implements the operation `other in self`:

> ```
> def __contains__(self, other):
>     """
>     Returns True if self has at least the same flags set as other.
>     """
>     if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
>         raise TypeError(
>             "unsupported operand type(s) for 'in': '%s' and '%s'" % (
>                 type(other).__qualname__, self.__class__.__qualname__))
>     return other._value_ & self._value_ == other._value_
> ```

The empty set is a subset of any other set, therefore `Functions.CLEAR in Functions.x` is true for any `x`.

Or, in terms of the concrete bitwise operations that are performed, `CLEAR` is 0, so `CLEAR in x` evaluates `0 & x == 0` which is always true.